# How to force BeautifulSoup to output HTML-entities

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-entities

BeautifulSoup can easily convert html-entities, when parsing a document.

However, is there a way, to reverse this step when turning it into a string, so that I can get parseable output again?

Here is what I get:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<p>a&lt;b</p>", convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
<p>a<b</p>
```

Here is what I would like to get: `<p>a&lt;b</p>`

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find any API solution, I use this monkey-patch to achieve the desired result:

```
from BeautifulSoup import NavigableString
__nv_str__str__ = NavigableString.__str__
NavigableString.__str__ = lambda self, encoding=None: __nv_str__str__(self, encoding=encoding).replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;")
```